# Getting info from selected mail item in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office

I want to write an add-in for Outlook 2010. The idea is - user selects one mail item in folder, then presses the button on ribbon which starts the add-in. Add-in gets information from selected item, process it and displays result.
I run in to problems when trying to get the Inspector of selected item. I tried:

```
Outlook.Inspector Point = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.Inspector;
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Point.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
```

Of course this doesn't check if current item is actually an mail item but that's for later. My problem is, when i try running the program i get NullReferenceException.
The only working examples of this I found on web was with [event handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx#Y684). But I want to start add-in on button press..

I am trying to make this in .NET 3.5 not 4

Answer (score 5):

The [`ActiveInspector()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863939.aspx) is the window that opens when the user double-clicks a mail item in the [`Explorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860356.aspx) window. If the user is just viewing [`MailItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861332.aspx) in the reading pane - you won't have an active inspector window (*hence the `NullReferenceException`*).

You are probably looking for the [`Explorer.Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861267.aspx) to get access to the currently selected [`MailItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861267.aspx).

```cs
 Outlook.Selection selection = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
```

Comment: It still gets me NullReferenceException. Maybe that's because I select an item in Explorer window and then navigate in ribbon to press my custom button?

Comment: `selection` is a `NullReferenceException`? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes. Maybe i screwed up calling method? I have ribbon class and addin class. In order to get to addin class method i create an object in ribbon class and call the method. http://pastebin.com/ABy46Qjj

Answer (score 3):

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application to get the Application object. That's probably your null reference, there is no Application object on "this" within the ribbon class.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link that helped me a lot to sort out Outlook interop issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184621.aspx - and it does show how to enumerate currently selected items as well.