# Get selected mail items in Outlook Explorer with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to convert some VBA code I have put together into an Outlook addin in order to avoid having to run the macros in reduced security environment.

I know just enough VBA and VB6 to dabble in writing stuff I use for myself and this is my first foray into VB.Net.

I just installed Visual Studio (Community Edition) and the conversion from VBA to has gone smoother than I expected thanks to suggestions by the IDE apart from one or two issues.

One of these is trying to get the items selected in Outlook which I had based on the code provided here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868001.aspx

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim x As Integer 

    myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer ' => This generates an error
    myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
    For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
        If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then 
            Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x) 
            ' Do Stuff 
        End If 
    Next x 
End Sub
```

I am unable to get around the error message generated by `Application.ActiveExplorer`.

Any advice on how to convert this to VB.Net? I have searched high and low but all the examples I have found are VBA based.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816828/getting-info-from-selected-mail-item-in-outlook-2010) comes close but I can't make the leap between the languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hard study, I managed to resolve this using the equivalent of:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Sub GetSelectedItems() 
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application  
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection = myOlExp.Selection
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim x As Integer 

    For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
        If (TypeOf myOlSel.Item(x).Class is MailItem) Then 
            oMail = myOlSel.Item(x) 
            ' Do Stuff 
        End If 
    Next x 
End Sub
```